How do I force dotnet publish to use Release configuration on a solution with multiple modules
We have a central .NET solution that uses multiple modules which each have its own .csproj and .sln, currently they use .NET 7.
I am trying to publish all of the modules and force them to all use Release configuration.
However when I used the command dotnet publish -c Release with the central solution, it ends up applying debug configuration with the individual projects. The -c only works if I run each project and publish them one by one themselves instead.
Please help.
Let's say we have a central_solution.sln, which includes individual C# projects project1.csproj and project2.csproj.
I tried using command (built from TeamCity):
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish central_solution.sln --framework net7.0-windows --runtime win-x64 --no-build -c Release @C:\TeamCity\BuildAgent3\temp\agentTmp\2.rsp

I also tried it a different way like this:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish central_solution.sln --framework net7.0-windows --runtime win-x64 --no-build @C:\TeamCity\BuildAgent3\temp\agentTmp\2.rsp -p:Configuration=Release

Both times, project1 and project2 have their debug binaries used to publish instead of the release binaries from the build.

what happens when you remove --no-build?

Confirm that the Release configuration in the solution is mapped to the Release configuration of each project.

The --no-build is used is because we have a separate pipeline used to build the project in teamcity, this tag is there to separate the Publish step so that it doesn't rebuild again. I can confirm the release configuration in the solution is mapped to the release configuration of each project, as during the build step, the release/debug configurations are correctly executed.

You build both release and debug in the build step? Are the solution build and solution publish actions within the same TeamCity Build? If no, are the two TeamCity builds always performed on the same agent and in the same working directory?

Well.. We normally only build release in the build step. Except for that with this new publish step from the main solution, it errored at first, showing a filenotfound exception, with path pointing at debug build location which didn't exist, it only started working once I manually built a debug version, which it still kept grabbing debug build for the publish. The build and solution publish actions are within the same Teamcity build normally, and always by the same agent.

You can try to set the projects to "Release" during "BeforeBuild" in your main project's csproj file:
 <Target Name="SetDependenciesToRelease" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <MSBuild Projects="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" Properties="Configuration=Release" />
    <MSBuild Projects="..\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj" Properties="Configuration=Release" />
</Target>

or use BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" and build dependencies individually

There is no "main project". A .sln file is being used.

That's right! @Eljimo how do You evaluate that binaries are built using "Debug"?

Yeah, the .sln is used for the 'main project' so there is no way to do this, thanks for suggesting though. As for the "Debug", I check the timestamp of Debug binaries created from the build and compare it with the Release binaries, and can see that the Published files are taking Debug binaries somehow, which I don't understand why as I did specify Release in configuration.

Internally, MSBuild generates a project from the solution (.sln) file.
